# What are the advantages ManageIQ has over OpenStack Horizon? I am currently working on Horizon but was wondering if ManageIQ is better

Tags: web-applications, cloud, virtual-machine, openstack-horizon, manageiq

What is the difference between those two? I want to control resources down to the user level from the dashboard. Just wanted to know what are the advantages of using ManageIQ or Horizon.

Comment: Can you reopen this question? It focuses on describing the difference of two very different tools which appear to be very similar, but they are not. Even if the tools would be similar - the answers provide the same technical discussion as why somebody would use Apache over Nginx server or vice versa. Please, reconsider this option @maximilian-peters

Answer (score 4):

What is the better option? It depends on your needs...

**ManageIQ** provides the tools to manage multiple clouds (OpenStack, Amazon) or infrastructures (VMware vCenter, MS HyperV, oVirt) through a single application. Resources can be provided through VM requests or by ordering the Catalog items. The user/authorisation management supports creating department hierarchy and the policies of the request handling and deployment, which means that the administrator defines which data should be provided in the request and who should approve it. **ManageIQ is application for enterprises with multi-cloud environments**. It can be overkill for a single cloud/user management.

**Horizon** is a part of OpenStack and it is more simple and straight forward. It will provide more simple resource/user management for a *smaller* OpenStack based cloud environment. With the Horizon you will be limited on managing resources only from OpenStack.

Answer (score 3):

ManageIQ provides:

- Inventory. Understanding what is there, even for different environments (i.e more than one OpenStack)
- Automation. You can automatically trigger provisioning workflows (i.e. integrating with Foreman, Ansible, etc)
- Compliance. Being able to create policies and enforce them.
- Self-service. Not just creating an instance, but a full solution, orchestrating between different components. Like HEAT templates, but more focused on the end user.
- Reporting. Generating reports, dashboard and chargeback for different users.